# How to squash my changes into a single result commit and pick into master branch?

Tags: git

Let's suppose I need to perform some average-length (several days) refactoring.

I create "mybranch" from master, do the work, sometimes I perform merges from master to mybranch (some other team members supposed to continue the work, and probably I'll need to get their changes). And after a while I'm ready to merge my changes back to master.

Will I be able to squash **only my changes** (excluding the changesets with merges from master, since they aren't mine) and cherry-pick a single result commit of my works into the master? Is it a possible to do scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep.  You can confirm it with a small test repository.  Just do:

```
git rebase --interactive master mybranch
```

and choose `squash` for all the lines except the first.  Then you just checkout `master` and do a regular fast-forward merge of `mybranch`.

Comment: Oh, it even will be a fast forward? Without requirement to cherry-pick it? "for all the lines except the first" --- what is `first` in this case? And could I squash all except merges (I suppose I'll do several merges from master in the process of the work)

Comment: Correct.  Rebase always produces a fast-forwardable history.  Essentially you resolve all the conflicts before the merge instead of after.

Comment: The `--interactive` option pops up a list in your editor.  Just leave the commit it puts on top as "pick."  The merge commits probably won't even show up, but even if they do, it's not an issue because you're merging it back into `master` anyway.

Comment: Also, don't forget to enable rerere with `git config --global rerere.enabled 1`.  That will help keep you from having to resolve any merge conflicts twice.

Comment: "it's not an issue because you're merging it back into master anyway" --- yep, it not an issue, but I just don't want to have more "clean" diff. Anyway, give me a day to experiment with it ;-)

Answer (score 4):

After rebasing, there will be no reference on those commits in previous "mybranch"

What I will do and could be more safety is that

```
git checkout mybranch
```

Create a branch (it is actually a temporary branch for rebasing purpose)

```
git checkout -b movingToMaster
```

Try to rebase the `movingTomaster` to `master`

```
git rebase -i master
```

An editor will be prompted out asking you which commit should be picked, or squashed or edit...

Edit that files, in your case, the first line should keep remain the same and the other line should change "pick" into "squash", you can amend your commit message if you want to. 
Save it after you make enough change on that file.

i.e.

```
pick 0a81405 Bug Fix 1
pick 91be655 Bug Fix 2
pick 1200fc7 Bug Fix 3
pick 1211fb7 Bug Fix 4
pick ba77fdf Bug Fix 5
```

Change to

```
pick 0a81405 Bug Fix 1
squash 91be655 Bug Fix 2
squash 1200fc7 Bug Fix 3
squash 1211fb7 Bug Fix 4
squash ba77fdf Bug Fix 5
```

Save it. Then

```
git checkout master
```

Move your `master` branch to `movingTomaster` branch by using Fast forward merge

```
git merge movingTomaster
```

Note: it will be no harm since it is only a Fast-Forward Merge and would not clutter your history.

Delete your movingTomaster branch if you want to

```
git branch -D movingTomaster
```

Comment: Yep, got you. Thanks. But cannot get the line "and move your master branch to movingTomaster branch"

Comment: @zerkms: at that point, your master branch still does not have that "single" commit. Your movingTomaster branch should be now one more commit ahead then master. (you can visialise by gitk command) You need to move your master branch up to the same commit point with movingTomaster

Comment: How that "move" could be performed? Isn't it just a merge (fast-forwarded in this case)?

Comment: @zerkms: yes `git merge movingTomaster`, it is only a FF merge, so it won't affect your commit history at all.